# mod_rewrite all requests to one file except particular directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website and I want to rewrite all requests on my site to a single page.  However, if there are requests for particular sub directories I want those requests to be processed as usual.

Here's my current .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^lib/(.*)$ lib/$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^scripts/(.*)$ scripts/$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^styles/(.*)$ styles/$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^tpl/(.*)$ tpl/$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^services/(\w+)$ services/$1.php [END]
RewriteRule ^services/(\w+)/(\w+)$ services/$1.php?id=$2 [END]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.html [END]
</IfModule>
```

If I go to `site/scripts/ascript.js` it works: the script is delivered. All of the rules work except for the lib rule.

If I go to `site/lib/something.js` it doesn't work, index.html is delivered.

Why is the lib not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^lib/(.*)$ lib/$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^scripts/(.*)$ scripts/$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^styles/(.*)$ styles/$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^tpl/(.*)$ tpl/$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^services/(\w+)$ services/$1.php [END]
RewriteRule ^services/(\w+)/(\w+)$ services/$1.php?id=$2 [END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.+$ index.html [END]
```